# Angular 13 to 14 migration issue running widgets

Tags: angular

We have a parent angular application and one of its key feature is programmatically adding selected angular applications as **widget on top of our parent angular application** and the widget are mostly built on **Angular 14 **while our parent angular application is built on **Angular 6.1.0.**

The widgets are dynamically instantiated/added/removed on the page with the following lines of code appended/removed on the html:

```
 <div class="calc"><app-root-widget>loading ....</app-root-widget></div>

    <script src="http://localhost:4200/assets/scripts/widget.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4200/runtime.js?build=1709600028" type="module"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js?build=1709600028" type="module"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4200/styles.js?build=1709600028" type="module"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4200/scripts.js?build=1709600028" defer=""></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4200/vendor.js?build=1709600028" type="module"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4200/main.js?build=1709600028" type="module"></script>
```

We've decided to update the parent angular application starting from version 6, 7, 8 up to version 13 and so far everything still works and our dynamically added widgets render successfully.

Migrating to Angular 14, our application works as expected on everything except that feature of rendering an angular widget/application failing. We've already tried many things and our widget still seems to fail to render on top of an Angular 14 application.

Can someone please help advice what we need to do or check in order for our child angular widget/application to successfully run on top of an Angular 14 application. The weird thing is that there's no errors being thrown and our widget just fail to render which successfully renders up to Angular 13!

Thanks in advance!

1. We've tried adding the lines of code mentioned above on an html manually and run the html just to confirm that our single Angular application/widget will render and it does.
2. Trying incremental updates moving from Angular 6 until 13, for each update iteration, our widget still run successfully.